# Issue with Python Code

Tags: python

For some reason my code is only converting AUD to USD no matter which option I Choose. I was wondering where I went wrong and what I missed.
Thanks in Advance

## Currency converter

```
AU = 1.000000
US = 0.790541
EU = 0.638550
GB = 0.566447
TU = 0.335597
SW = 0.740017

def menu():
    input("Whould you like to convert to AUD or AUD to another Currency?
    \nConvert to AUD\nConvert From AUD")
    
    if 2:
        int(input("Which Currency do you want to convert to AUD\n1: US\n2: 
        EU\n3: BP\n4: TU\n5: SW"))
        if 1: 
            value = int(input("How much money in AUD do you want to 
            convert?"))
            print("You now have",value*US,"In USD")
        elif 2:
            value2 = int(input("How much money in AUD do you want to 
            convert?"))
            print("You now have",value2*EU,"In EU")
        elif 3:
            value3 = int(input("How much money in AUD do you want to 
            convert?"))
            print("You now have",value*GB,"In GB")
        elif 4:
            value4 = int(input("How much money in AUD do you want to 
            convert?"))
            print("You now have",value*TU,"In TU")
        elif 5:
            value5 = int(input("How much money in AUD do you want to 
            convert?"))
            print("You now have",value*SW,"In SW")
        else:
            print("Incorrect Option, Please Try again.")
            menu()
print("Welcome to Currency Converter")
menu()
```

Comment: `if 2:` and `if 1:` are always true. There is *no comparison here*. You appear to have forgotten to assign the result of the `int(input(...))` call to compare that result.

Comment: Thanks , Im still a llittle confused. Could you give me an example

Answer (score 3):

The `input()` function returns a value, but you haven't used it. Your statement

```
if 2:
```

is always true (because `2` is not zero). Here is where you would use the return value returned by `input()` from the previous statement. Use something like:

```
choice = int(input("..."))
if choice == 2:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The right side of an `if` statement is evaluated. So when you write

```
if 2:
```

The computer converts this to a [boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) value (either True or alse). For integers, all numbers but 0 are converted to True, so this code always runs.

Use a [variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers) to store the result of `input`, and compare that to 2:

```
answer = int(input("Whould you like to convert to AUD or AUD to another Currency?
    \nConvert to AUD\nConvert From AUD"))

if answer == 2:
```